# Loop radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 36 questions and every question has 2 radio inputs for answers. The inputs are named i1-i36 and j1-j36. I am trying to count the checked radios into a variable for the ones named i and in another var the ones named j.

Tried this but it didn't work:

```
function test_it(entry) {
if (entry.value!=null && entry.value.length!=0) {
entry.value=""+ eval(entry.value);
}
computeForm(entry.form);
}
function computeForm(form) {
var rasa=0
var rasb=0

for (var count=1; count<37; count++)
{
if (form.i[count].checked){
var rasa=rasa+1;
} 
}


for (var count=1; count<37; count++)
{
if (form.j[count].checked){
var rasb=rasb+1;
} 
}

document.getElementById('showa').innerHTML = rasa;
document.getElementById('showb').innerHTML = rasb;


<body>
<form METHOD=POST>
Question 1
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="i1" VALUE="1">A1
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="j1" VALUE="0">A2
[...]
Question 36
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="i36" VALUE="1">A1
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="j36" VALUE="0">A2
</form>
</body>

// I want to get these:

<span id='showa'>Result a</span>
<span id='showb'>Result b</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<input type="radio">` name attribute should be same like this

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

here name is gender
First change your name attribute like this

```
Question 1
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="j1" VALUE="1">A1
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="j1" VALUE="0">A2
```

and to check length use this

```
$(':radio[name="j1"]:checked).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use a for loop, but use highly order function like map, filter etc..

In this case substitute the for loop with:

```
var rasa = 0
var rasb = 0
form1.map((element, index) => {
    if(element.checked)
        rasa++
})
form2.map((element, index) => {
    if(element.checked)
        rasb++
})
```

Another thing, in every for loop you are re-declaring rasa and rasb and you don't need to. Also `<form method="POST">` the property should be lowerCase.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
radios = document.getElementByTagName('input');

a = 0
b = 0

for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
  if(radios[i].name.contains('i')
    a++;
  else
    b++;
}
```